# Django runserver error: _frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 139824587568800

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After adding `'rest_framework.authtoken'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` (settings.py) and running `python manage.py migrate` I started to get a strange error when trying to run django server (the strange thing is, that the error appears on every 2nd or 3rd attempt, sometimes the server starts running without the error):

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 79, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 12, in <module>
    from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.test.client import encode_multipart
  File "/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/blogapi-nhgDNK6P/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.test import signals
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 149, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 94, in acquire
_frozen_importlib._DeadlockError: deadlock detected by _ModuleLock('django.test.signals') at 139824587568800
```

I am using: `django 2.2.7` and `django rest_framework 3.10.3`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ticket on Django's issue tracker discussing similar issue: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30352.

For a temporary fix, you can remove all `.pyc` files on your project and run the `runserver` command again.

```
find <path-to-your-project> -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

NB: I use `pyenv` which stores the project's virtual environment in a different directory outside the project directory. Removing only the project's `.pyc` files work for me, but you may also try removing the virtual environment's `.pyc` files if needed.

---

For anyone who still gets this error, please kindly comment in [the issue page](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30352) to help Django developers reproduce and fix the error.